# How to set default node version on another new shell with mac?

Tags: node.js, nvm

I use mac and `brew install nvm`.

Then I try these command on terminal:

```
1 echo "source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh" >> .bash_profile
2 . ~/.bash_profile
3 nvm install 14.16.0
4 nvm alias default 14.16.0
5 node -v
```

I can see `v14.6.0`

Then I open another terminal type `node -v` it's still `v10.22.0`

I hope the node version is `v14.6.0` not `v10.22.0` in new terminal.

Type `echo $PATH` print

```
/Users/motogod19/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/motogod19/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/motogod19/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/motogod19/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/motogod19/Library/Android/sdk/emulator
```

How do I fix it ?

Comment: I typically do `nvm use 14.16.0` when I want `nvm` to use a specific version of Node. I see you set the default alias in line 4. But I'm curious if using `nvm use` before line 5 would print the updated alias version.

Comment: after `nvm install 14.16.0` will set like `nvm use 14.16.0`